# How can I replace a text in PowerPoint with a image

Tags: image, replace, vbscript, powerpoint

I created a PowerPoint slide with three textboxes and named them as "LEFT", "TEXT", "RIGHT".

I can already replace the text using vbscript but now my problem is how to replace LEFT and RIGHT with images from a local file?